# How to expand floated child div to its parent's height

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside a div. One of the two is floated to the left and it has some links in it. It has a width of 200px The second of the two has a value of overflow:hidden and it has a width of rest to the right. It has some content in it which makes its height longer than first div.

I want first div to expand to parent's or the second div's height according to the increment of the second div's height

```
<div id ="main">
    <div id ="first">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div id ="second">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
#main{
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#first{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}

a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
}
#second{
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djobkh7t/9/)

Comment: You can use display:table; for that, check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your problem is: first you have to give a `height` to the parent `div` and then set the height of the child, `#first` to `min-height: 100%`, the code would be like this:

```
#main {
overflow:hidden;
border:1px solid black;
height: 400px;
}
#first {
border:1px solid black;
width:200px;
float:left;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. It was my fault, i should have written that height of div is not known. It changes according to the content of second div(or longer div). I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table;` applied to the #main container and `display:table-row;` and `display:table-cell;` applied to #first and #second to make the first child container take the height of its sibling container #second. Remember to add `overflow:auto;` to allow the first container to make it expand its height until the bottom.

**CSS**

```
#main{
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#first{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    display:table-row;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;   
}
a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
}
#second{
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:400px;
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/djobkh7t/7/

Comment: The first div does not takes the height of second's. It goes down and has the same height. Even in your jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the floats and changed the display types on your divs to fix the problem. See example CSS + fiddle:

```
#main{
border: 1px solid black;
display: table;
width: 500px;
}
#first{
border: 1px solid black;
width: 25%;
display: table-cell;
}
#second{
border: 1px solid black;
width: 75%;
display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djobkh7t/13/

You can set the display type of 'table' on the parent div, then 'table-cell' on the child div's.